# Convert Object array into String array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

How can I convert this object array into a string array? I'm reading records from a firebase collection.

```
    firebaseDB.collection("message").document(key).collection("messages").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        }
        else {
            self.driverArr.removeAll()
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                let msgdata = document.data() as! [String:Any]
                var msgObj = Message()
                if let name = msgdata["name"] as? String {
                    msgObj.name = name
                }
                self.driverArr.append(msgObj)
            }
            if self.driverArr.count < 1 {
                print("No Drivers")
            }
            else{
                print("*** Driver Names array ***")
                print(self.driverArr)
            }
        }
    }
```

The current output of this array is:

> [MainApp.Message(name: Optional("Oliver"), userId: Optional(""), msg:
>   Optional(""), creatAt: Optional(0), latitude: Optional(""), longitude:
>   Optional("")), MainApp.Message(name: Optional("Bluesona"), userId:
>   Optional(""), msg: Optional(""), creatAt: Optional(0), latitude:
>   Optional(""), longitude: Optional("")), MainApp.Message(name:
>   Optional("Oliver"), userId: Optional(""), msg: Optional(""), creatAt:
>   Optional(0), latitude: Optional(""), longitude: Optional(""))]

I wish to simply output an array that contains an Array of strings with the names `["Oliver", "Bluesona"...]`

Comment: Try this if let name = msgdata["name"] as! String {
                    msgObj.name = name
                }  OR  self.driverArr.append(msgObj!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `compactMap` to get all the valid names in the array.

```
print( driverArr.compactMap({$0.name}) )
```

Comment: please let me know your answer and this code gives same result? `let arrNames = driverArr.map({ (doc: document) -> String in
                doc.name
            })
            print(arrNames)`

Comment: No, first thing you are using `map` which doesn't filter out `nil` values. Second, `driverArray` is supposed to be of type `Message` since you are appending `Message` objects to it. `let arr = driverArr.compactMap { (message) in
    message.name
}`

Comment: Thanks for reply but i want to confirm that both gives same result right?

Comment: Suppose if i have Object array that contains `Int`, `String`, `Bool` values and if i want to get only all int value as array then your `.contactMap` and `.map` works as same?

Comment: @Denis The last line in my last comment gives the same result. You need to change the `String` return to `String?` and the argument is a `Message` not document.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for your guide.